# Confusion with flagging system

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits, disputed-flags

I marked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38793310/c-sharp-net-mvc-web-application-using-word) as *too broad*.

My flag was marked as **disputed**, but the question was kept *on-hold* for being *too-broad*.

I'm not sure if this is due to an error in the system, or because of the [reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/13240990) here as suggested by someone in chat room.

---

I also have questions on some of my **disputed** flags.

1. [Some
   answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37261265/how-can-i-send-an-email-via-c-sharp-and-get-the-email-address-of-the-sender-with)
   was marked *low quality*; it was *disputed* in my history, but the
   answer seems to have got removed!
2. Do we not consider [this
   answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added/38056309#38056309),
   and [this
   answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22134393/objective-c-compiling-with-clang-on-linux-foundation-foundation-h-linking-file/38230434#38230434)
   as *low quality* post?

The reason for asking the point 2 here is to understand how the *This is a test* question! I remember I failed in a couple of tests and learnt that a *good answer* must contains *some good amount of description with good example*; but these reviews appear to be conflicting with the system tests.  Am I wrong in marking them as *low-quality* answers?

Please advise me on this so that I can be more effective in reviewing and flagging in the system.  Thanks

Comment: This is some nice meta regarding when/how to flag and review answers [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) then continue with this [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your question closure flag was disputed due to [the unanimous "Looks OK" reviews you point out](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/13240990). The funny thing is, your flag also triggered a Close Votes review, where [reviewers voted unanimously to close the question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/13243372). I'll say that at least one of the reviewers of the former won't be doing so again for a while.

In regards to the two "very low quality" flags you had disputed, those flags should be used for items that require immediate deletion. The first was on a question that did not seem to require that, and reviewers disputed it. The second was on an answer that does not qualify as a link-only answer (even if you removed the links, the answer is still viable), so reviewers disputed that as well. Those reviews I agree with.

Comment: I think *too broad* flag status should come from *Close Votes Review* rather than *Triage Review*.  Would it be impacted by both? If so, Is my flag successful? Can anyone change?

Comment: "your flag also triggered a Close Votes review"? or was it TylerH close vote that triggered it?

Comment: @PetterFriberg It's the flag.